# I am getting stuck in a loop with my webscraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am making a webscraper and when I try to grab one page of data it keeps loading the same information.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

my_url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#read page 
page_html = uClient.read()
#close page
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#finds all realtors on page 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"agent-list-card clearfix"})

for container in containers:
    name = page_soup.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
    agent_name = name.text.strip()

    number = page_soup.find('div', class_='agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs')
    agent_number = number.text.strip()

    print("name: " + agent_name)
    print("number: " + agent_number)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps loading the same information"? Why should it load different information if you scrape the same page?

Comment: Because you search in `page_soup` and not in `container`!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to search in `container` and not in `page_soup` within the loop.

Additionally you should either check if there is a result or catch the thrown exception.